# Populate weekly calendar with available slots dynamically

Tags: calendar, scheduling

I want to create a weekly calendar which shows like this

### < Prev Week                   OCTOBER 2015                     Next Week >

### Sun 18       |Mon 19        |Tue 20|Wed 21     |Thu 22|Fri 23       |Sat24

### 11A.M.-12A.M.||10A.M.-11A.M.|      |4P.M.-5P.M.|      |11A.M.-12A.M.|    |

### 3P.M.-4P.M.  |1P.M.-2P.M.   |      |           |      |             |    |

### |3P.M.-4P.M.   |      |           |      |             |    |

### |5P.M.-6P.M.   |      |           |      |             |    |

These are the time slots in which a person is available in a week.The number of slots and time at which the person is available varies from day to day.I need to populate the time slots from a json data. Each slot is like a button in that day which can be clickable if that slot is available else it will be disabled.I searched for calendars, but everywhere i am getting calendars with time slots on the left side which i don't wan't. Someone please suggest me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After too much of struggle i realised that this can be done by customizing the full calendar plugin. http://fullcalendar.io/